# Why my print statements and logging.info is not shown in pytest html report

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I found this issue while running a test case in pytest framework in which once the test completes (either pass or fails) On report.html I am getting `"No Log Output Captured"` when i click on show details on each test cases.
**report.html**

[image: report.html]
command I use to get html report: `pytest test_01.py -s -v --html=report.html`

In console I am able to get the print statement. however is there any possible ways that I can get the same in report.html as well?

**console output:**

```
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                      
------------------------ Test 1 Initiated: Verify LogRetention file count in dropbox ------------------------
Device rebooting...
------------------------ Test 1 PASSED successfully : Verify LogRetention file count in dropbox folder ------------------------


Test case took 118.19 seconds.

 test_01.py::test_verify_file_count ✓
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use logger instead of print

```
import logging

def test_example():
    # Set up the logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    # Example log messages
    logger.debug("This is a debug message")
    logger.info("This is an info message")
    logger.warning("This is a warning message")
    logger.error("This is an error message")
    logger.critical("This is a critical message")
```

You can also use `--capture=tee-sys` to see both stdout and log output

```
pytest --capture=tee-sys
```

I hope it helps

Comment: if I use print and give --capture=tee-sys I am able to get log output in report html but if i change them to logger I am neither getting output in console not in report html.

Comment: Make sure you have set up the logging module. Configure logger to capture log messages. Set the log level you want to use (e.g., DEBUG, INFO, etc.). 
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

Comment: what is **name** here?

Comment: sorry, I meant to say ```(__name__)``` which is the module name. It's rem

Comment: now, I am getting logs in html but not in console, I wanted in both areas.

Comment: Are you using ```--capture=tee-sys```  and have you configured the logger? it should work

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Add "--capture=tee-sys" in the command that you are executing in the terminnal.

ie.

pytest -v -s file.py --html=report.html  --capture=tee-sys